# Dynamically setting ml-gradle properties

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I need to set an ml-gradle property (mlModulesDatabaseName) within the build script itself. I was under the impression that the gradle-y way to do that was to use the extra modules extension:

```
ext {
    mlModulesDatabaseName = 'Modules'
}
```

This seems to place the value inside the project.properties map as it would if it was read from the gradle.properties, but its doesn't seem to target the correct database when I attempt to run the mlReloadModules task:

```
$ ./gradlew mlReloadModules -Pdev
:mlDeleteModuleTimestampsFile
:mlClearModulesDatabase
Clearing modules database
Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging: {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"404", "status":"Not Found", "messageCode":"XDMP-NOSUCHDB", "message":"XDMP-NOSUCHDB: xdmp:database(\"my-app-modules\") -- No such database my-app-modules"}}
Unable to clear database; cause: 404 Not Found
Finished clearing modules database
:mlPrepareRestApiDependencies
:mlLoadModules
:mlReloadModules

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

This may be ignorance of how gradle scopes its properties on my part, but you would think this would work. Any suggestions on how to pull this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can remember `ml-gradle` reads properties immediately after being applied as a plugin. This means all changes to properties after this line

```
apply plugin: "com.marklogic.ml-gradle"
```

have no effect. Have you tried setting your `ext` properties before applying the `ml-gradle` plugin?

Edit: 
Another way to set custom properties is to set them like this:

```
ext {
    mlAppConfig {
        modulesDatabaseName = 'Modules'
    }
}
```

This also works after the `apply plugin` line.

Comment: Yup.  That's what I was looking for. Both of these suggestions work for me. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify - when the ml-gradle plugin is applied, all of the properties are read in and used to set values on the AppConfig object that's referenced by mlAppConfig. So within an ext block, you can manipulate the mlAppConfig object.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the gradle properties plugin. Put something like this at the top of your build.gradle file if you don't have it already:

```
plugins {
  id "net.saliman.properties" version "1.4.6"
  id "com.marklogic.ml-gradle" version "3.7.1"
}
```

Once you have saliman properties plugin in place, you can drop your dev-specific properties in a file called `gradle-dev.properties`, and run with `-PenvironmentName=dev` to enable them.

By default it will look for both `gradle.properties` and `gradle-local.properties`. It will always read both the `gradle.properties` as well as the environment-specific properties file (if exists). The latter will override properties from the first.

Depending on the specific tasks, you can also override properties from within `build.gradle`, but I'd avoid doing that with tasks that come with ml-gradle out of the box.

HTH!

Comment: For posterity, I should note that this is the better answer if you're engineering your gradle script properly.  So anybody that is looking for a similar answer, I'd go this way. Sadly, I'm retrofitting ml-gradle into a legacy script that would make this hard(er) so I couldn't use it here.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share another approach which I use to run `ml-gradle` tasks within MarkLogic Data Hub Framework (`DHF`) projects. In `DFH` development, I sometimes need to run a same task on either the staging DB or the final DB. So I use a `GradleBuild` task to wrap around the `ml-gradle` task and set the project properties within the `GradleBuild` task.

```
task myFinalDbTask(type: GradleBuild) {    
  tasks = ['myMlGradleTask']
  startParameter.projectProperties = [
    database: mlFinalDbName,
    port: mlFinalPort
  ]
}
```